# Where can I find ipv6 blacklists

Tags: iptables, ipv6, ipset

We have blacklists in place to stop traffic from known bad actors. There are plenty of resources such as the lists below but I am not finding any results for ipv6 blacklists. Does anyone know where I can find such lists?

```
    "https://www.projecthoneypot.org/list_of_ips.php?t=d&rss=1" # Project Honey Pot Directory of Dictionary Attacker IPs
    "https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py?ip=1.1.1.1"  # TOR Exit Nodes
    "https://www.maxmind.com/en/high-risk-ip-sample-list" # MaxMind GeoIP Anonymous Proxies
    "http://danger.rulez.sk/projects/bruteforceblocker/blist.php" # BruteForceBlocker IP List
    "https://www.spamhaus.org/drop/drop.lasso" # Spamhaus Don't Route Or Peer List (DROP)
    "http://cinsscore.com/list/ci-badguys.txt" # C.I. Army Malicious IP List
    "https://lists.blocklist.de/lists/all.txt" # blocklist.de attackers
    "http://blocklist.greensnow.co/greensnow.txt" # GreenSnow
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/firehol/blocklist-ipsets/master/firehol_level1.netset" # Firehol Level 1
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/firehol/blocklist-ipsets/master/stopforumspam_7d.ipset" # Stopforumspam via Firehol
    "http://ipverse.net/ipblocks/data/countries/cn.zone" # Ban an entire country, see http://ipverse.net/ipblocks/data/countries/
    "https://www.threatsourcing.com/ipall-free.txt"
```

EDIT: I see the URL to SpamHaus however that is for mail abuse. I am looking for overall abuse (e.g. DNS amplification attacks, SSH bots etc.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DNSBLs for IPv6](https://serverfault.com/questions/258752/dnsbls-for-ipv6)